# Export to Spreadsheet option missing from Actions in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, list, excel, export, survey

I am unable to export a SharePoint List (Survey) to a spreadsheet.
The option "Export to Spreadsheet" is missing from the Actions dropdown menu for the list.

I've done lots and lots of searching for this issue, but no luck.

A few things that I verified:

- Client Integration is enabled for the Authentication Provider on my Web Application
- I am in the Overview view (default) for the list
- SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection Features is active
- I have an Excel Services Application up and running
- My client which I use to access the list has Office 2013 installed (no other versions of Office)

Any ideas? Thanks for any responses in advance!

Edit - Also relevant to the question is that I am accessing the list as farm/site collection administrator, so I should have the permissions to export to spreadsheet.

Comment: Which browser are you using? And if you are using IE are you certain that it is not IE 64 bit?

Comment: I am using IE 10 64 bit. I have a few colleagues though who use the same browser, without any issues, and we've also tested it in Chrome. I seem to be the only one having the problem, doesn't matter which browser I use.

Comment: Once you said IE 10 you killed my theory... Do you have the same issue if you log onto one of the PCs your colleagues use?

Comment: Yeah, I just tested accessing the same survey from one of my colleagues' clients. Same behaviour.

Comment: I noticed some strange things on my SharePoint farm. The User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization Service Applications had gone haywire and wouldn't start. I tried removing and adding them, but I gave up. We ended up exporting the VHDX from my colleague's environment and setting up a new one for me. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's little bit too late but maybe I can help someone else..
U can use the export to spreadsheet option only on your default view of the list. (SP2013 & Online)

Knowing that, you know you should now open your survey list from sharepoint designer and set one of the views as default.. Reload survey in your browser, 2-3 times (using the ctrl + f5) and the export option should appear again. 
That's because sometimes while you are editing your default view, after saving, it loses its "default view" flag..

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm - Circus Ranger has the right of it.
For SP2013 I had a customized form on my Survey which caused the Export to Excel option to vanish from the dropdown. But more than that - I also changed the default view to the modified view.

Upon restoring Overview.aspx as the default view, the option reappeared and everything worked as expected! This was after attempting the various other fixes listed around the internet.